# SASS/Stylus - Define a List Dynamically

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I started playing with SASS and Stylus but I'm having trouble pushing elements onto a list.

For instance:

```
$names: adam john wynn mason kuroir

.photos
  @each $name in $names
    .photo-#{$name}
      background: image-url("avatars/#{$name}.png") no-repeat
```

I want to add my name to the `$names` list without re-specifying all the existing names. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you dynamically generating this SASS file? What's the case where you would have to re-specify the existing names?

Comment: @maxbeatty: I'm coding a basic (variable column) grid system using a `for` loop to define the columns `width` and I want to move all the other properties that are common to all column classes (like `display` and `float`) into a comma delimited declaration (`.span1, .span2, ..., .spanN`), to save bandwidth.

Comment: [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) accomplishes that with `.row>[class*="span"]{display:inline;float:left;margin-left:20px;}`. Any direct child descendent of the container `.row` with a class containing `span` will be assigned those common styles. Doesn't answer your question but solves your problem :)

Comment: @maxbeatty: I know how they do it but TB uses LESS (and LESS has no support for loops). I would imagine a meta-language that supports loops also has some way of concatenating values into a new selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stylus equivalent command is `push()`

```
names = (adam john wynn mason kuroir)

names = push(names, myname)
```

See here http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/bifs.html

Answer (score 3):

Experimenting with Stylus, I've tried to re-create a standard CSS list of selectors that all have the same property like (example 1) `.col-01, .col-02, .col-03 { display : block }` using Stylus' `push()` function, which breaks if you try to do something like this:

```
  sizes = small medium large

  for size, i in sizes

     for num in ( 1..12 )

         columns = push( .column-{size}-{num} )
```

However, if you do something like this instead

```
  sizes = small medium large

  for size, i in sizes

     for num in ( 1..12 )

        .column-{size}-{num}
            display  block
            float    left
```

It works, but the compiled CSS is verbose

```
.column-small-1 { display: block; float: left }
.column-small-2 { display: block; float: left }
.column-small-3 { display: block; float: left }
 etc
```

There is a way to reproduce example 1 using Sylus' `@extend`, although it is slightly hackish

```
.column
   float  left 

sizes = small medium large

for size, i in sizes

   for num in ( 1..12 )

       .column-{size}-{num}
             @extend .column
```

This method does produce the desired output.

EDIT:

You can demarcate a class using `$` instead of `.` notation — so the original class does not produce any compiled css

```
$column
   float  left

sizes = small medium large

for size, i in sizes

   for num in ( 1..12 )

       .column-{size}-{num}
             @extend .column
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sass you have [`append`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#append-instance_method) method:

Examples:

```
append(10px 20px, 30px) => 10px 20px 30px
append((blue, red), green) => blue, red, green
append(10px 20px, 30px 40px) => 10px 20px (30px 40px)
append(10px, 20px, comma) => 10px, 20px
append((blue, red), green, space) => blue red green
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to accomplish this with Stylus:

```
names = (adam john wynn mason kuroir)

.photos
  for name in names
    .photo-{name}
      background: image-url("avatars/%s.png" % name) no-repeat
```

**EDIT:** I totally misunderstood the question. I don't know how to add to the list, in stylus nor in SASS.